# Regex to return two numbers?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that fits these parameters:

```
print('twonum:',
    '3,4' in tn,
    '3.0, 4.5' in tn,
    '-3.14159265 1110' in tn,
    '3.4.5, 1' not in tn,
    '1   2' not in tn,
    '3 - 4' not in tn)

for match in regex.twonum.finditer(text):
    if match.group(0) == '3,4':
        print('  match1:', '3' in match.groups(), '4' in match.groups())
    if match.group(0) == '-3.14159265 1110':
        print('  match2:', '-3.14159265' in match.groups(), '1110' in match.groups())
```

But I can only make it match the `'3, 4'` in pythex. It still returns False for the first three. It does return True for the last three, which it should. `match1` and `match2` are still a mystery.

This is my regex so far:

```
pattern2 = '\'[\d](,)?[\d]\''
twonum = re.compile(pattern2)
```

What should I do to make it fit the given parameters?

Answer (score 0):

```
'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:(?:, ?| )-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*'
```

You can try this.
[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LFiKZZ/1/)